# PERL: converting string and sending to URL via GET

Tags: perl

I like to convert the two variables and pass them into this url.

What is the best way to convert the string into gets string syntax for the url?

(UNIX_COMMAND AND PERLMAPHASHDATA)

thanks

```
my $PERLMAPHASHDATA = &MEC_GRAPH_DATA($APPENDIXDATA, $HASHDATA, $DOWNLOAD_FILE_PATH, \%USER_SELECTION);
my $UNIX_COMMAND = '/proj/gordon/runme.cgi -PERMAPHASH DATA';

print qq|
    <script>
        \$.get("scripts/DBD_SQLite/mysqlite_SAVE_SEARCH.cgi", function(data){\$("#tabs-112").html(data)});
    </script>
|;
```

Comment: I do not see where the variables `$PERLMAPHASHDATA` and `$UNIX_COMMAND` are used after declaration. Please [amend your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4650867/edit) with the relevant piece of code so the answers can be certain instead of guessing your intentions.

Comment: Also, the second piece of code looks like jQuery. How is that related to the issue?

Comment: yeah, I didn't use the PERLMAPHASHDATA AND UNIX_COMMAND VALUES yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear what you are asking to do.

If you want to know how to take an arbitrary string and encode it so it's safe for use in URL string (URL/URI encoding, e.g. turning "=" into "%3D"), the usual Perl way to do it is [URI::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aEscape) module.

```
use URI::Escape;
$safe = uri_escape("10% is enough\n");
```